# Insert multiple values for several id

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to insert multiple ids on multiple dates on a temporary table without adding an INSERT for each line. Here is what I expect to find in my table :

```
100 | 2020-06-01 17:00:00
100 | 2020-06-02 17:00:00
100 | 2020-06-03 17:00:00
202 | 2020-06-01 17:00:00
202 | 2020-06-02 17:00:00
202 | 2020-06-03 17:00:00
555 | 2020-06-01 17:00:00
555 | 2020-06-02 17:00:00
555 | 2020-06-03 17:00:00
```

My current SQL :

```
select f.id, to_date('2020-06-01 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from file_r f;
select f.id, to_date('2020-06-02 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from file_r f;
select f.id, to_date('2020-06-03 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from file_r f;
```

Where my ids are in the file_r table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you not familiar with the syntax: `INSERT INTO table ... SELECT ...` ? More details here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php

Comment: Is the date range fixed for each ID? Like it always start with a particular date and end on a particular date?If yes, then it means you just need a `row generator` for dates and join it with your ID table. See [**Row generator between two dates**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)

Comment: @Abra actually I've got a range set much larger than in the example. I should probably have be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate DATE values by using CONNECT BY, and use the generated values in a CROSS JOIN.  (Although there is an answer already, maybe the following example is a bit easier to understand.)

**Table containing unique IDs**

```
create table file_r (
  id number unique
) ;

insert into file_r( id )
select 100 from dual union all
select 202 from dual union all
select 555 from dual ;
```

**CTAS (create table as select)**

```
-- You can create the temporary table "on the fly"
create table temptbl( tid, tdate )
as
select id, dt 
from (
  ( select id from file_r ) -- unique IDs
  cross join
  ( 
    select 
      to_date( '2020-06-01 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) -- start date/time
      + ( level - 1 ) dt
    from dual
    connect by level <= 3 -- amount of days needed
  ) -- generated DATEs
) ;

-- datatypes of the TEMPTBL
describe temptbl
    Name    Null?      Type 
________ ________ _________ 
TID               NUMBER    
TDATE             DATE
```

**Query (temporary table)**

```
select tid
, to_char( tdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
from temptbl 
order by 1, 2
;


   TID    TO_CHAR(TDATE,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS') 
______ ________________________________________ 
   100 2020-06-01 17:00:00                      
   100 2020-06-02 17:00:00                      
   100 2020-06-03 17:00:00                      
   202 2020-06-01 17:00:00                      
   202 2020-06-02 17:00:00                      
   202 2020-06-03 17:00:00                      
   555 2020-06-01 17:00:00                      
   555 2020-06-02 17:00:00                      
   555 2020-06-03 17:00:00
```

You can - of course - create the TEMPTBL by writing some DDL code, and then INSERT INTO the TEMPTBL (instead of CTAS):

```
-- alternative
create table temptbl(
  tid number
, tdate date
, constraint id_date_unique unique( tid, tdate )
) ;

insert into temptbl( tid, tdate ) -- don't write VALUES ... here!
select id, dt 
from (
  ( select id from file_r ) -- unique IDs
  cross join
  ( 
    select 
      to_date( '2020-06-01 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) 
      + ( level - 1 ) dt
    from dual
    connect by level <= 3
  ) -- generated DATEs
) ;
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7c29c377c2d001229d505f18ddd89e6).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

- lines #1 - 5 represent sample data you already have in the `file_r` table (so you don't have to type that)
- query you do need begins at line #6

  - according to what you posted, you want to start from the 1st of current month at 17:00 (line #7)
  - for each `ID` found in the `file_r` table, you want to generate 3 rows (line #9)
- cross join with table function makes sure you'll avoid duplicates

---

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with file_r (id) as
  2    (select 100 from dual union all
  3     select 202 from dual union all
  4     select 555 from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7         trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 17/24 + column_value - 1 datum
  8  from file_r cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                                             connect by level <= 3
 10                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by id, datum;

        ID DATUM
---------- -------------------
       100 2020-06-01 17:00:00
       100 2020-06-02 17:00:00
       100 2020-06-03 17:00:00
       202 2020-06-01 17:00:00
       202 2020-06-02 17:00:00
       202 2020-06-03 17:00:00
       555 2020-06-01 17:00:00
       555 2020-06-02 17:00:00
       555 2020-06-03 17:00:00

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```